# How to convert VOB files to AVI?

Tags: windows-xp

```
VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP
VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO
VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.BUP
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.IFO
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB.idx
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB.idx
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_2.VOB
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_3.VOB
VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_4.VOB
```

I have a DVD. How can I convert these VOB files to an AVI file? (ex.: 700 or 1400 MByte AVI file?). The program should recognize that that there are several VOB files! OS: windows xp

Answer (score 5):

You should look at Handbrake. It's a pretty sweet program that will look at your directory selected and show you which chapters you want to convert. You can select the largest chapter even if it's in several VOB files.

http://handbrake.fr/

*HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder, available for MacOS X, Linux and Windows.*

Comment: :D -1... i selected the VIDEO_TS directory with handbrake, and it only converted 1 chapter....it took 2,5 hours...and in the end the AVI file didn't had any audio part..great :D

Comment: Make sure that you read their documentation. They give a lot of options and you'll want to make sure that you're setting it up properly. Their default settings should take the file down to about 700MB and compress the audio. Maybe you used an audio setting that you did not have a codec for during playback? Try using VLC to see if it has the audio.

Answer (score 0):

FFMpeg is the swiss army knife of video. [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) is a frontend for windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ***AutoGK***. http://www.videohelp.com/tools/AutoGK

Its probably not developed anymore AFAIK, but its still a good one-click solution to convert DVDs to an AVI(Xvid+MP3) file of your desired size. It also has a few other other options to control your output. In my experience, it leads to excellent quality files in most cases. Takes very long though on slow PCs.

If you prefer manual settings, there's a quite advanced tool called ***Gordian Knot***, which has a LOT of options for fine tweaking your output. Not recommended until you are a video enthusiast. AutoGK is meant to be automated solution to this. http://sourceforge.net/projects/gordianknot/

You can also use ***FairUse Wizard***, it supports current technologies such as H264/AAC codecs and MP4,MKV containers and is easy to use. http://fairusewizard.com/

***Handbrake*** is great too, and supports lots of formats. http://handbrake.fr/